# How to properly install MS VC++ 9 runtime?

Tags: visual-c++, runtime

I have an application that uses the ms vc++ runtime. How should I install it on the end-user's system if it is not present? I was thinking of bundling it with the installer... but how would I do that as far as what to include? Is there some silent installer? If so, where can it be found? I can't seem to find it in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [interesting post](https://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/10/12/how-to-redistribute-the-visual-c-libraries-with-your-application.aspx) about deploying the runtime libraries on [the Visual C++ blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/10/12/how-to-redistribute-the-visual-c-libraries-with-your-application.aspx). The post is about VC8 so I'm not sure all the recommendations apply to VC9.

Here are your options according to Microsoft:

- Use an .msi installer including the .MSM files for the VC
  libraries you're using. These MSM
  files install the libraries globally.
  They also keep a reference count so
  that the libraries are removed when
  the last application using them gets
  uninstalled.
- Use "app-local"
  deployment i.e. copy the
  libraries and manifest files in your
  application directory. This is a simpler
  solution if you don't use an .msi
  installer. Your app should still use the
  system version of the libraries if they are more
  up-to-date than your own.
- Link everything statically (and avoid crt usage across dll boundaries)

Another option Microsoft discourage you from using is running the Visual C++ redist installer from your own installer.

I'm not sure what their reasons are. It will take a few extra megabytes and will not be reference counted but it still works very well AFAICT. You can pass the /q option to vc_redist_x86.exe to perform an unattended install (no user interaction).

Comment: The first and last are not an option, (the installer must be an .exe and the program will not link with the static crt) and the middle option is what I am doing currently - I just hoped there would be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

It has it's own [installation program](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en). I've seen it usually run as a prereq step of a larger installer.

Comment: How can I install it silently before my program's files are copied? The installer I use allows bundled executables like this but I need to know what args to use when launching the msvcr_x86.exe installer to hide its installation.

Answer (score 0):

One way or the other, you need to list it in your manifest. So you might just as well deliver it as via SxS in your application rather than try to deliver a global copy to the target machine. SxS is a big hard subject, sadly. Hopefully someone will supply an answer with more details and I'll delete this one.